# Drupal Decoupled in AWS: best architecture

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, drupal, headless

I am the architect of a Drupal 7 monolitch website in AWS Elastic BeanStalk using other AWS resources like CloudFrount, ElastiCache, RDS...
Now I am planning to migrate to a Drupal 9 decoupled website.
In a decoupled scenario you need to use a front-end framework like React.
This can be handled without problem with an Elastic BeanStalk using Node.js.
The problem is how to implement backend service (Drupal 9 Data backend) without building another Elastic BeanStalk.
What is the best solution?
Can I use AWS Lambda@Edge to implement ReactJS components and call Drupal Rest endpoints?